# Error Building Hadoop 2.6.4 on OS X:

Tags: maven, hadoop, java-8

[INFO] Apache Hadoop Annotations .......................... FAILURE [  1.212 s]

I'm getting an error building Hadoop 2.6.4 on OS X.  I tried various ways of skipping the Javadoc code, but it's still not working.

```
$ mvn clean package -DskipTests -DskipDocs -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true

$ mvn clean package -Pdist -DskipTests -Dtar -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true

$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T08:41:47-08:00)
Maven home: /opt/local/share/java/maven3
Java version: 1.8.0_05, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.11.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

E.g. Here's sample output.

```
[ERROR]   symbol:   class AnnotationDesc
  location: class ExcludeHandler
/Users/davidlaxer/hadoop/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-annotations/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/classification/tools/RootDocProcessor.java:[226,11] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Doc
  location: class ExcludeHandler
/Users/davidlaxer/hadoop/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-annotations/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/classification/tools/ExcludePrivateAnnotationsJDiffDoclet.java:[36,11] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable LanguageVersion
  location: class ExcludePrivateAnnotationsJDiffDoclet
/Users/davidlaxer/hadoop/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-annotations/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/classification/tools/ExcludePrivateAnnotationsJDiffDoclet.java:[42,16] error: cannot access Doclet
[ERROR]   class file for com.sun.javadoc.Doclet not found
/Users/davidlaxer/hadoop/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-annotations/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/classification/tools/ExcludePrivateAnnotationsStandardDoclet.java:[35,11] error: cannot find symbol
```

Comment: http://blog.joda.org/2014/02/turning-off-doclint-in-jdk-8-javadoc.html

Comment: hadoop 2.7.2 builds!